# Merging Android unit test and connected test code coverage data is broken

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, android-studio-3.0

Version 2.3.3 of the Android Gradle Plugin was able to provide merged unit test and connected test code coverage data.  In version 3.0.0, this capability is broken because each of the test types use a different and incompatible version of JaCoCo.  Rafael Toledo provided [a Medium blog post](https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/setting-up-an-unified-coverage-report-in-android-with-jacoco-robolectric-and-espresso-ffe239aaf3fa) showing how to make this work with 2.3.3. I have provided [a Github repo](https://github.com/pajato/acc) that illustrates the working code and the broken code in a few branches.  The [repo documentation](https://github.com/pajato/acc/blob/master/README.md) provides a Readers Digest description of the problem.  At this point I am convinced the Gradle Plugin team owns the issue and will file a bug shortly.  My questions are:

1) Can anyone suggest a viable workaround? (there is a suggested fix by Carmen Alvarez posted to the Medium blog post but I get no joy from it.)

2) Can someone point me to instructions on how to hack and build the Gradle Android Plugin to test out a potential fix? (I found the answer to this one at http://tools.android.com/build/gradleplugin )

Answer (score 3):

According to [Android Plugin DSL Reference](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.html#com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension:jacoco) that contributes Android specific things:

> To specify the version of JaCoCo you want to use, you now need to include it as a buildscript dependency in your project-level build.gradle file, as follows:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>       dependencies {
>         classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:<jacoco-version>"
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

Previously Android Plugin had

```
android {
    jacoco {
        version = "<jacoco-version>"
    }
}
```

According to [Gradle JaCoCo Plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.2/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:configuring_the_jacoco_plugin) that contributes task of type `JacocoReport`:

> The JaCoCo plugin adds a project extension named jacoco of type JacocoPluginExtension, which allows configuring defaults for JaCoCo usage in your build.
>
> ```
> jacoco {
>     toolVersion = "<jacoco-version>"
> }
> ```

And so here is modification for your https://github.com/pajato/acc that allows to align versions so that execution of `./gradlew clean jacocoTestReport` succeeds:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.9"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "jacoco"
    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.7.9"
    }
}
```

Comment: As near as I can tell, the toolVersion property only applies to the test report but not to the connected test coverage data generation by the Android Gradle plugin.  Bottom line is that when I run your changes, I now get no error but also no data in the generated report.  So a step in the right direction but not a solution, yet.

Comment: @pajato0 buildscript dependency applies on the generation of the connected test coverage data by the Android Gradle plugin, otherwise you'll be getting the same error as originally. The emptiness of report is because all classes to be analyzed (directory `intermediates/classes/debug`) are excluded by filter. No idea why this version of Gradle Android Plugin doesn't place your classes into this directory, however seems that they are present in jar in `intermediates/classes-jar` directory, so that maybe you can try to use these ones for generation of report.

Comment: good point on the original error.  I am working on the missing code point.  Your observation is helpful.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am running into a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427286/unit-test-and-connected-test-jacoco-execution-data-format-differ-causes-sonarqu?noredirect=1#comment83845695_48427286

Comment: Last I checked, this is still broken.